# Loading specific tape volumes using mtx

Tags: tape

I am trying to extract data from a set of tapes. Currently, there are five of them in the tape-magazine.

I have tried using the `mtx` command without much success.

Heres the output of

```
mtx -f /dev/sg1 status
mtx: Request Sense: Long Report=yes
mtx: Request Sense: Valid Residual=no
mtx: Request Sense: Error Code=70 (Current)
mtx: Request Sense: Sense Key=Not Ready
mtx: Request Sense: FileMark=no
mtx: Request Sense: EOM=no
mtx: Request Sense: ILI=no
mtx: Request Sense: Additional Sense Code = 04
mtx: Request Sense: Additional Sense Qualifier = 8E
mtx: Request Sense: BPV=no
mtx: Request Sense: Error in CDB=no
mtx: Request Sense: SKSV=no
READ ELEMENT STATUS Command Failed
```

Here is the output of the `tapeinfo command`

```
tapeinfo -f /dev/sg1

Product Type: Medium Changer
Vendor ID: 'BDT     '
Product ID: 'FlexStor II     '
Revision: '4.70'
Attached Changer: No
SerialNumber: '00DE65202403_LL0'
TapeAlert[21]:Clean Periodic:The tape drive needs to be cleaned at next opportunity.
SCSI ID: 0
SCSI LUN: 1
Ready: no
```

Comment: What's your actual question ?

Comment: I have five tapes in the tape magazine. Is there a way to load them through the command-line?

Comment: You should edit your question and add your actual question to it. Did you try  `mtx load <slotnum>` ? What happend ? ...

Comment: I have updated the question. Thanks for responding.

Comment: That `mtx` output often means the tape magazine door is still open.  Is the autoloader fully closed-up and ready to go?

Comment: The output from your load command looks just like the output of your status command from earlier - is that correct ?

Comment: I see the same error with status and load.

Comment: @MadHatter That's unlikely. But I have no means to verify it as I am accessing it remotely.

Comment: Hang on a minute.  That `tapeinfo` information says you're talking to a *tape drive*.  Tape drives can't changes tapes.  *Autochangers* change tapes, and `tapeinfo` says that's not one.  Try `mtx -f /dev/sg1 status`, see if that works.  And maybe even `sg2`, etc.  If that doesn't work out, the output of `cat /proc/scsi/scsi` would be useful.

Comment: Same error though. But yes, tapeinfo shows that its a medium changer. I have updated the question with the output from these

Comment: If the output from `mtx -f /dev/sg1 status` is identical, then I think we're at the point where you need remote-hands-and-eyes to go stare at the tape library, and see what it's telling you.  I'm *very* suspicious that the door is open.  Some libraries have NICs and web interfaces, which could tell you more if this one had one and you knew the config details.  But failing that, remote-hands-and-eyes.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The device has a web-interface too but its not being used. Will take at look at tomorrow. 

I did find something in the mtx faq though. It mentions the same error with the loader set to "sequential".

http://mtx.sourceforge.net/faq.html

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comments, I was able to solve the problem.

After changing the auto-loader from "sequential" to "random", I was able to use the `mtx` command to load the tape using its id.